# Trying to add numbers from a file subtrack them and put them into another file

Tags: python, file

```
file = open("byteS-F_FS_U.toff","r")
f = file.readline()
s = file.readline()
file.close()
f = int(f)
s = int(s)
u = s - f
file = open("bytesS-F_FS_U","w")
file.write(float(u) + '\n')
file.close()
```

This is what its says when I run the code :

```
f file.write(float(u) + '\n') TypeError:
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

I am trying to load numbers from a file that gets new numbers every few seconds.
When they're loaded they're subtracted and put into another file. I am a new python Programmer.

Comment: And what is the problem you are having? why is the code you provided not working?

Comment: This is what its says when I run the code :                                                                            f    file.write(float(u) + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to put full path of the file you're trying to open!

With that first thing fixed, I created a loop program which opens the file every 10 seconds and writes the result to the other file. Exceptions are handled so if another process is writing in the file while being opened/read it does not crash. Python 3 syntax.

```
import time

while True:
    try:
        file = open(r"fullpath_to_your_file\byteS-F_FS_U.toff","r")
        f = int(file.readline())
        s = int(file.readline())
        file.close()
    except Exception as e:
        # file is been written to, not enough data, whatever: ignore (but print a message)
        print("read issue "+str(e))
    else:
        u = s - f
        file = open(r"fullpath_to_your_file\bytesS-F_FS_U","w")    # update the file with the new result
        file.write(str(u) + '\n')
        file.close()
    time.sleep(10)  # wait 10 seconds
```

Comment: When I run the code I get  a new message saying read issue [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'F:\\Server\\Frames\\Server_Stats_GUI\x08yteS-F_FS_U.toff' And not getting a file being made at the same time. Shouldn't  there only be 1 slash instead of one?

Comment: When I rerun the code it says     file.write(float(u) + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: sorry fixed that! and double antislashes are what's printed. Actually there is only one slash by directory separator

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do float + string, then you should do smth like:

```
"{0}\n".format(float(u))
```